# How to autoformat API response in .NET core 5 Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I Have an API with formatted response look's like this following JSON:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "totalRecord": 2,
    "message": "Succesfully get merchants",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Leo Shop",
            "address": "Flower Street 9A",
            "isComplete": false,
            "createdAt": "2021-05-30T14:16:27.654233",
            "updatedAt": "2021-05-30T14:16:28.515476"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Test Shop",
            "address": "Playing Street 12A",
            "isComplete": false,
            "createdAt": "2021-05-30T14:16:27.654233",
            "updatedAt": "2021-05-30T14:16:28.515476"
        }
    ]
}
```

And code behind those response look's like this following code :

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Merchant>>> GetMerchants()
{
    var data = await _context.Merchants.ToListAsync();
    ApiResponse res = new ApiResponse{StatusCode = 200, Message = "Succesfully get merchants", TotalRecord = data.Count, Data = data}; // Focus on this line
    return Ok(res);
}
```

My question, how to automatically convert default response As `ApiResponse` model without repeating to write `new ApiResponse()` model on every action return inside every controller?

Hopefully anyone can help me.. Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Your return value doesn't look right: you're not returning a list of `IEnumerable<Merchant>` you're returning a single instance of your response object are you not ?

Comment: You can create middleware that will intercept the response and modify the repsonse body to incorporate your ApiResponse class.

Comment: Have a look at AutoMapper: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos...what serialization option will eliminate the need to new-up an ApiResponse in every endpoint?  This question seems more about eliminating repetitive code.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting it?

Comment: Do you really need a message like this? When you get a successful response from the WebAPI, it will have the HTTP code 200. The number of records received is known in any case. The message "Successfully get merchants" duplicates already known information: "Successfully" - code 200, "get merchants" - the WebAPI address to which you made a request. So I would return just an array of data, as recommended according to the Web API guidelines.

Comment: @auburg Yes, it is. but there is no error when I running. But I will check it again.. Thank **auburg**

Comment: @Big Daddy Yes..this is about eleminating repetitive code. And yaa...it is very possible to use middleware, but maybe because my limited understanding, so I didn't solve this yet.. Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Is this the best practice? But how if I need total record for pagination? Well .. I think this is good idea.. **Thanks Petrov**

Comment: For pagination purposes, of course, you need to specify additional parameters in the response. But you should not duplicate the information that is already available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Result Filter in MVC Filter pipeline

[MVC Filter pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index/_static/mvc-endpoint.svg?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

So change your controller looks like this

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<List<Merchant>> GetMerchants()
{
   return _context.Merchants.ToListAsync();
}
```

Add new class, called ResultManipulator.cs

```
  public class ResultManipulator : IResultFilter
        {
            public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
    
            public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
            {
                //run code immediately before and after the execution of action results. They run only when the action method has executed successfully. They are useful for logic that must surround view or formatter execution.
                var result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
                var resultObj = result.Value;

    //change this ResultApi with your ApiResponse class
                var resp = new ResultApi
                {
                    Path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.HasValue ? context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value : "",
                    Method = context.HttpContext.Request.Method
                };
    
                if (resultObj is not null && resultObj is not Unit)
                    resp.Payload = resultObj;
    
//you can also change this from System.Text.Json to newtonsoft if you use newtonsoft
                context.Result = new JsonResult(resp, new JsonSerializerOptions()
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
                    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
                });
            }
        }
```

And dont forget to add ResultManipulator class in Startup

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new ResultManipulator());
            })
```

I hope it solve your problem

Comment: Is this possible to use in .NET core 5 web API project? because I thought, I did'nt use MVC for this project. Thank you **Vendy**

Comment: ofc its possible in netcore 5 web api project, its about the pipeline request middleware built-in inside .net core framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a middleware solution.  It will transform the response.

```
public class YourResponseMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;    
        public YourResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var existingBody = context.Response.Body;
            using (var newBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = newBody;
                await _next(context);
                var newResponse = await FormatResponse(context.Response);
                context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
                newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.Body = existingBody;
                var newContent = new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEnd();
             
                // Send modified content to the response body.
                //
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(newResponse);
            }
        }
    

        private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
        {
            //We need to read the response stream from the beginning...and copy it into a string...I'D LIKE TO SEE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS
            //
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var content= await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();    
            var yourResponse = new YourResponse (); // CREATE THIS CLASS
            yourResponse.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            if(!IsResponseValid(response))
            {
                yourResponse.ErrorMessage = content;
            }
            else
            {
                yourResponse.Content = content;
            }
            yourResponse.Size = response.ToString().Length;
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourResponse );

            //We need to reset the reader for the response so that the client an read it
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);    
            return $"{json}";
        }

        private bool IsResponseValid(HttpResponse response)
        {
            if ((response != null)
                && (response.StatusCode == 200
                || response.StatusCode == 201
                || response.StatusCode == 202))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

 public static class ResponseMiddleware
    {
        public static void UseYourResponseMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<YourResponseMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs (Configure())

```
 app.UseYourResponseMiddleware();
```